# How to select only the most recent 6 entries based on current time?

Tags: sql, time

What I have is a database for a Dallas Bus Station. My goal is to select only the 6 most recent buses that have arrived. What I have now will select all bus arrival times since midnight to now. I tried something like select Top 6, followed by my comparison, but that failed.

This code works for all times 00:00:00 - NOW, but I want most recent 6 that occurred before NOW.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.BusSchedule
WHERE DATEPART(HH,BaseArrive) < DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(time, getdate()))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT    *
FROM      dbo.BusSchedule
WHERE     DATEPART(HH,BaseArrive) < DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(time, getdate()))
ORDER BY  BaseArrive DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY;
```

Essentially get all of the rows, order them by their date in reverse to get the most recent first and get the top 6 of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 6 *
FROM dbo.BusSchedule
WHERE DATEPART(HH,BaseArrive) < DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(time, getdate()))
Order By BaseArrive desc
```

Edit: I see you mentioned that using top 6 didn't work for you. It's the solution I would tend towards in this type of problem, but perhaps if you explain more about what was wrong about it I can help guide you to an answer.